# How do I check if a solution is feasible for a model in Gurobi?

Tags: gurobi

I have built my model, and I have a specific point which I would like to know if the point is a feasible solution to the constraints. Is there a command to do this?

Comment: This will help you: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360056102052-Test-if-the-start-solution-is-feasible

Comment: The link says to iterate over the constraints and check for myself. Why doesn't Gurobi have a command to do this? It's a basic task that I want to do many times

Comment: Also you can fix all variables to start value using bonds of variables.